# Sharepoint REST - How to search a specific SharePoint site? API calls returning results from all sites I have access to

Tags: rest, sharepoint

I want to setup an API call for a specific search term on a project SharePoint site.

So per the documentation, the call I should be using is this:

```
https://{site_url}/_api/search/query?querytext='XXXX'
```

The `site_url` looks something like `COMPANYNAME.sharepoint.com/sites/PROJECT_NAME/`

The problem is that the results from the API call return results *from every SharePoint site I have access to*, not just the Project site I am interested in.

I assume I'm missing something straightforward - could someone who is familiar with the SharePoint API give me a hint?

Comment: After a bit of googling - apparently there is no way to natively return results from one site collection only. Which seems mad to me! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/900689/sharepoint-rest-search-all-files

Comment: As a workaround - does anyone know how to format a sharepoint API search query to limit results to a single site?

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try using SharePoint search REST API endpoint like below and see if it works for you:

```
https://{site_url}/_api/search/query?querytext='XXXX AND Path:https://COMPANYNAME.sharepoint.com/sites/PROJECT_NAME/'
```

**References**:

1. [How can I search a specific subsite using the REST API in SharePoint?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/100726/how-can-i-search-a-specific-subsite-using-the-rest-api-in-sharepoint-2013)
2. [SharePoint search REST API - get all results from 2 sites and filtered results from one site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/550180/sharepoint-search-rest-api-get-all-results-from-2)

Comment: Seems to have worked, thanks. Unfortunately the response form the sharepoint API is mostly unparseable XML dross, so might give up on this.

Comment: Check this thread once to parse the search results: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/243466/using-the-json-results-from-a-sharepoint-api-search-response